# word for something like blessing

Tags: vocabulary

Consider these occasions where I don't know what word should I use :

> Keep on giving part of your income to charities. It will give your
>   money ... and causes your wealth to increase.

and

> Letting disabled people to work for your company will give your wealth
>   ... and brings more fortune to you.

I'm not a preacher but I want to know what is a proper word for these situations. Is there any very suitable word to fit into theses sentences ?

Comment: Did you try searching for synonyms of "blessing"? before you took the arduous task of forming this question.

Comment: @Argot yes, none was what I mean.

Comment: Benediction is the word that makes some sense to me,and I strongly detest the use of "causes" here.

Comment: @Argot why ? what is the problem of "causes"?

Comment: Superstitious beliefs are contradictory to causes . Cause doesn't seem right ,simply stating "increases your wealth" seems right.

Comment: I agree with Argot about "causes". You're talking about karma or something similarly woolly, yes? "Cause" is too concrete for that.

Comment: I cannot parse either sentence. Can someone rephrase them for me? I must be missing something.

Comment: Slightly rephrase to improve: *will **activate** your wealth ... and brings* (wealth that lies idle serves no purpose, putting it into active use can serve a good cause).

Comment: I am now putting this on hold because the more I think about it, the more obvious it becomes that the whole sentence is just clumsy and will have to be rewritten from scratch. In other words, choosing a word for that position is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sanctify" or "consecrate" come to mind for this meaning.

*"Keep on giving part of your income to charities. It will (sanctify or consecrate) your money and increase your wealth."*

> **Sanctify:**
>
> verb
>
> 1. set apart as or declare holy; consecrate.
>
> "a small shrine was built to sanctify the site"
>
> synonyms: consecrate, bless, make holy, hallow, make sacred, dedicate to God

Comment: I liked sanctify. It seems that it is the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **Integrity** could fit into!

Integrity: Adherence to moral principles; honesty